# What is the difference between the keyword 'Private' and 'Final'?

Tags: php, oop, methods, visibility, final

Having a confusion between `Private` and `Final` in PHP.

For example I have 3 classes:

1. Class A (parent class)
2. Class B (child class)
3. Class C (other class)

What I understand:

- A: ***Public*** variables and methods are accessible to the class A, class B and class C
- B: ***Private*** variables and methods are only accessible to the class A.
- C: ***Protected*** variables and methods are only accessible to the class A and class B
- D: ***Final*** methods are only accessible to the class A not to class B.

My Question is:

> After using private we can achieve functionality like final then why we use final?

I am asking this question only for my clarification for myself.

Comment: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) The final methods are accessible for the child class if the visibility is something else than private. You just can't overwrite them in the child class. So the difference is final methods can still be accessed by other classes depending on the visibility, but you can't overwrite them as normal methods

Comment: it means final methods of class a are not accessible to class b but class c can access them.

Comment: It depends by it's visibility. The keyword final doesn't change anything of the accessibility of the method. It only defines if another class can overwrite it (When it has access to it). But the access is defined by they keywords: `private`, `public`, `protected`

Comment: You're welcome, should I convert it into an answer?

Comment: yes, you can convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to make it clear, the keyword `final` doesn't have to do anything with the visibility of a method. The visibility of a method is defined by the keywords: `public`, `protected` and `private`.

The final keyword defines if another class can overwrite the method or not (if a method is final it can't be overwritten by antoher class), when the other class has access to the method. Otherwise it won't even have access to the method, so it neither can use/call the method nor overwrite it.

Also only methods can be final it can't be used with properties.

---

A, B and C are correct and as I said above the keyword final doesn't have anything to do with the visibility, so D is not correct.

For more information see the corresponding manual pages:

- [`final` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php)
- [property and method visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Since PHP 8.1 properties may also be final.

Answer (score 1):

Final classes or methods can **NOT** be override.

From php doc

> PHP 5 introduces the final keyword, which prevents child classes from overriding a method by prefixing the definition with final. If the class itself is being defined final then it cannot be extended.

Example from php documentation:

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
   public function test() {
       echo "BaseClass::test() called\n";
   }

   final public function moreTesting() {
       echo "BaseClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   public function moreTesting() {
       echo "ChildClass::moreTesting() called\n";
   }
}
// Results in Fatal error: Cannot override final method BaseClass::moreTesting()
?>
```

More details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Answer (score 0):

The property `final` of a method is used to make clear to the compiler that the given method can not be overrided somewhere else.

As a result, if we declare a function as a `final` and then we try to override it somewhere else, we will get a `warning` or a `fatal error`.